# correct syntax browser sniffing (createElement) < ie9

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, createelement

Source Code:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') != -1 && parseInt($.browser.version, 10)<7)
```

Edited - sorry, posted wrong code.

What's the correct formation of the above, to identfiy browsers less than ie9?

thanks

Edit -

Here's the reason for the code above:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') != -1 ) {
                    hidden = document.createElement('<input type="hidden" name="' + atName + '" value="' + attrId + '"/>');
                } else {
                    hidden = document.createElement("input");
```

it's for the createElement issue in anything lower than IE9

Additionally, I would love to rewrite the entire function, but due to scope I am unable to rewrite the file until it's included in a project - so I need to rewrite this one line to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` is not a valid javascript keyword. `VERSION` neither seems to be declared anywhere. Also I would recommend you to never test against a specific navigator or version but test against whether the browser supports the functionality you want to use. A technique called *feature detection*. So for example if you want to use the [HTML5's canvas element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element) don't test if the browser is XXX and the version is YYY. Test if the browser supports the HTML canvas element. [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) is an excellent library for this job.

---

UPDATE:

And if you don't want to hear about good practices and still insist on this browser version detection:

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 9) {
    alert('Warning, you are running a crap of a browser. Please upgrade!');
}
```

Comment: @Jason, no, it shouldn't be this way :-) Make it so that it shouldn't. You won't regret it.

Comment: not my decision - can't rewrite the entire file, I have to address this one line

Comment: @Json, what do you put inside the if or the else? What functionality do you need? It will be extremely easy to replace this buggy browser detection by a feature detection.

Comment: @Jason, you seem to be using jQuery already, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Jason, may I ask why on earth are you using `document.createElement` when you have jQuery? I mean you could simply write: `var hidden = $('<input/>', { 'type': 'hidden', 'name': atName, 'value': attrId });` and get rid of the whole ifs and stuff and let jQuery care about browser detection?

Comment: I would love to do that, but the scope of the project is literally to touch this one line that is repeated throughout the file, until it can be included in a project at a later date and re-addressed

Comment: @Jason, ok, see my update, but please promise you will never write anything like this in a new application.

Comment: I definitely won't. This code is 6-7 years old and not mine. But when the powers that be request a fix, and bill for time, and state the scope can only include this line - it's what I'm stuck with. So your edit identifies any IE browser lower than 9?